# App to user notification return true but not sending notification

Tags: facebook-graph-api, push-notification

I want to send or push a notification from graph api call. As shown in this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications).

What I did:
* make a Facebook web games app
* get user tokens
* same thing works 5 or 6 days ago but it stop working

[Graph api call image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpdwT.png)

[image: Graph api call image]

It **returns true but not sending notification. Why?** 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you send to many notifications to the same users during your testing ...? Pay attention to what the docs say, about stuff like the minimum CTR you have to maintain, otherwise Facebook might simply not deliver the notifications.

Comment: But I created new apps to test. It shows the same result.. :(

Comment: Here is the [issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1549630325132017/). Check this if someone also having this problem...

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you found the solution to this?

Comment: Nop, they didn't solve it fully.